# Handle Streaming video external Screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm here again with a new problem, basically now I got a requirement which the application needs to stream video on the mobile (Android), but it should not display the application content or the video in any other external output (if the application has a second output its should be showing a different layout), I've been trying to use some examples from Android and also looking at the API.

I can't show the external image in case it has another output presented. Any ideas how I can achieve this. am I missing something?

At the moment I'm trying to achieve my goal using MediaRouter, DisplayManager Presentation.

1 Option - Using MediaRouter

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MediaRouter mediaRouter = (MediaRouter) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);
        MediaRouter.RouteInfo route = mediaRouter.getSelectedRoute();

        if (route != null) {
             Display presentationDisplay = route.getPresentationDisplay();
             if (presentationDisplay != null) {
                 Presentation presentation = new DemoPresentation(this, presentationDisplay);
                 presentation.show();
             }
         }
         // Keep going here because theresnt presentation (secundary output) available

         setContentView(R.layout.video_player); 
        }
```

2 Option - Using DisplayManager

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDisplayManager = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    Display[] presentationDisplays = mDisplayManager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION);
    if (presentationDisplays.length > 0) {
        // If there is more than one suitable presentation display, then we could consider
        // giving the user a choice.  For this example, we simply choose the first display
        // which is the one the system recommends as the preferred presentation display.
        Display display = presentationDisplays[0];
        Presentation presentation = new DemoPresentation(this, display);
        presentation.show();
    }
    // Keep going here because theresnt presentation (secundary output) available

    setContentView(R.layout.video_player); 
}
```

This is Presentation

```
  private final class DemoPresentation extends Presentation {
   final PresentationContents mContents = null;

   public DemoPresentation(Context context, Display display) {
       super(context, display);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Be sure to call the super class.
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Get the resources for the context of the presentation.
       // Notice that we are getting the resources from the context of the presentation.
       // Inflate the layout.
       setContentView(R.layout.show_layout_external_screen);

  }
```

examples from  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html

Comment: Erm ... what is your question?

Comment: (Sorry I just edit my question) I can't show the external image in case it has another output presented. Any ideas how I can achieve this. am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean one screen playing video , another displaying thumbnails?

Comment: I want to be able to show always the video on the mobile screen but if theres any other output present I want to show (only in the second output another layout in this case an image)